# How to prevent a 404 when running my .NET 6 Web API as a self contained service?

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, self-contained, aspnetcore-environment

I have made a simple .NET 6 Web API. This works fine when running from Visual Studio (by just pressing F5). However, when running my application as a self-contained service I get a 404 for calls that are supposed to succeed. How can I make sure my self-contained service starts behaving the same?

Here is my `Program.json`

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices;


var options = new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default
};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Host.UseWindowsService();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.MapControllers();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
//app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapRazorPages(); });


await app.RunAsync();
```

Here is my `csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
      <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
      <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <UserSecretsId>XXXXX-78E75397-5A01-4397-9481-E423B4BF54C2</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="6.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This is how I test:

1. Open the solution file and press F5.
2. Run `dotnet publish --no-build -c Release` executed from the folder with the csproj in it. This generates an exe in side `XXXXX\bin\Release\net6.0\win-x64` so I run the exe from this folder by going to this folder from the command prompt and then run the exe.

In both situations, I test using `curl -I http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html` .

This returns a 404 when doing option 2 (with `dotnet publish`). When running from visual studio, I just get a 200.

How to make sure the result of `dotnet publish` behaves the same as my application behaves when running from Visual Studio?

Comment: You're running a self-hosted service in both cases. The other option is to use IIS. You get this error because you explicitly disabled Swagger unless the service runs in a development environment. That means you have to set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable to `Development` either in the user's Env variables, or in the shell before you start the executable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The service is self-hosted in both cases. The other option would be to use IIS.

The reason Swagger is disabled is because the code explicitly enables it only in a development environment.

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

The environment is controlled by the value of the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable. Unless you explicitly set that environment variable in a user's or system's Environment Variables, it won't exist, and your service will run in `Production` mode.

Shell scripts often set environment variables before executing programs that depend on them. Visual Studio sets the environment variables specified in `launchsettings.json` before launching your program. If you try to run the program outside VS you'll have to set them yourself, eg:

```
SET ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

myservice.exe
```

[launchsettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson) is used to [specify launch profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0), not just environment variables. This includes the hosting model, command line arguments and more. Typically it's used by an IDE like Visual Studio but you can also launch a  .NET program with [dotnet run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run) using a specific profile with the `--launch-profile <NAME>` option

The docs explain that this file isn't deployed, so it never appears in the `publish` folder:

> The launchSettings.json file:
>
> - Is only used on the local development machine.
> - Is not deployed.
> - Contains profile settings.